# Query state level db in Hyperledger Fabric using mutiple index sorting

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have to make query to couchdb in Hyperledger Fabric using sorting on multiple indexes. I have defined all the indexes properly and have tried using each of the index separately and its working fine. But as soon as I include two indexes together in one query it throws me the error:

```
Error:no_usable_index,  Status Code:400,  Reason:No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.
```

Here is my query that's not working:

```
{"selector":{"info":{"organization_id":"ABC123"},"status":{"$in":["STATUS1","STATUS2","STATUS3"]},"docType":"doc_awa"},"use_index":["_design/biltiDoc","indexbiltino"],"sort":[{"creation_date":"desc"},{"doc_no":"desc"}]}
```

Someone please let me know if its possible to use more than one sort index in the query?

Answer (score 0):

I finally have resolved it and the error is in the index definition. I have to define indexes in the same order as required while querying using sort.